# OpenTSDB some data lost

Tags: hbase, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, bigtable, opentsdb

I'm working with Google Cloud Platform GKE, 
and using kubernetes now.
I am trying to use OpenTSDB through google Bigtable and it's QA time.

but it has been unexpected bugs shown when I just put some data but, it is not shown. Even long time goes on, it's not shown anymore.

I used this image and tutorial (version and env are same)
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/opentsdb-bigtable

here is my steps.

1) put data with http POST request api
ex) `http://localhost:4242/api/put?details=true`

```
with Json object 
{
  "metrics": "foo.bar",
  "timestamp": "1483401600000",
  "value": 1.0,
  "tags": {
"foo": "bar"
  }
}
```

2) Confirm log, hbase console

3) Using GET API to query it
ex: `http://localhost:4242/api/query?start=1483401600000&ms=true&m=sum:foo.bar`

4) cannot see anything, just empty vector

Comment: Have you tried using an HBase client to connect to Bigtable and checking if the data exists there?

Answer (score 1):

https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/integrations#opentsdb has links to more documentation on OpenTSDB and Cloud Bigtable integration, including [Using OpenTSDB to Monitor Time-Series Data](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/opentsdb-cloud-platform). You can try updating to the latest version of [AsyncBigtable](https://github.com/OpenTSDB/asyncbigtable) and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

OpenTSB comes with a command line [client tool](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/cli/query.html) which you can try to debug with

> "..meant to be a quick debugging tool for extracting data from
>   OpenTSDB"

Also other utilities like filesystem check fsck too can be helpful in reporting and repair if there are issues with data. [Here](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/user_guide/cli/index.html) is a full list of command line tools.